# Database connection to another server

Tags: mysql, security, iptables

I have 2 Servers - one for PHP, and one for MySQL

Both servers are hardened - and now my question is, what's the correct way to set up a connection to the Database Server, from PHP?
Probably over SSH? Or is just the open MySQL port enough?

But if it's only over the open Port, how can I ensure that no bruteforce attacks try to get the root password, over that open Port? Can I somehow limit the IP access to the webserver? (if yes, how?)

Basically, I'm just asking what's the common / best way to set up / configure this kind of connection.

---

**further analysis**

I added iptables entries, added ufw entries (that basically generated the same iptable entries), etc, etc - sadly, nothing seems to work. My try to connect to mysql from the webserver, always gets blocked (I installed the `mysql-client` on the webserver, testing with the `mysql` commant - result: / `xxx` for obfuscation)

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx' (111)
```

I added `LOG` entries for iptables, and checked the `ufw` log, and `syslog` - but apparently, the package doesnt get blocked (no [UFW BLOCK]).
After searching a bit more, I guessed it could have been `apparmor` - but after installing `auditd` there are no visible blocks for `mysql`.

`netstat` shows mysql listening, on the correct port.

How can I analyze the issue further? What could be the reason for the blocking?

---

**Solution found**

Ironically, I found the answer 1 minute after the edit:

what was missing was a change in the mysql configuration file, namely `bind-address` had to be changed to the external IP.

The port protection works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that you server is hardened so you should be some way to reducing the risk already but check a few things.

- Ensure that your OS firewall only allows connections to MySQL from the php server. For a Linux server you could use iptables to do this

  `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s php.server.address --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`
  `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP`
- Ensure that the MySQL root user can only connect from the database server itself.
- Ensure that your databse users can only connect from your php server and that they only have sufficient privilege to do what's necessary.

  `GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.* TO 'someuser'@'php.server';`

---

As Lucas suggests you could add SSL to the connection - the MySQL manuals for this is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html).

Comment: I would also recommend to make sure he has SSL enabled

Comment: I tried your approach, and at first, it looked promising - but I still cant get the connections to work. I temporarily disabled ufw on both servers (php and DB server) - still, I couldnt even telnet on the mysql port (not even on port 80, but on the SSH port) - what could I do?

Comment: @Katai: I thought you wanted to know how to tighten up security on an existing system ?

Comment: @Iain: Of course, I just deactivated ufw to test if it's because of the firewall or not - the security apparently isnt the problem, since I _cant_ access the DB ;) (not even with the iptables entry). My problem is to find out where my Webserver gets blocked now (and I'm a bit too unexperienced as serveradmin to really know how to trace that back, I tried telnet to test the port, the only port working with telnet is the SSH port. I couldnt even access port 80)